# Can you apply collection functions to a descending IntRange?

Tags: kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin and found some behaviour that I did not expect.

This works:

```kotlin
println((1..10).map { it * 2 }) // [2, 4, ..., 20]
```

But this does not seem to iterate over anything and returns an empty list. I was expecting that I would get the reverse of the above list.

```kotlin
println((10..1).map { it * 2 }) // []
```

I didn't think a collection function should care about the order of the collection. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: ```..``` is used to create a range, and the start number must be less than or equal to the end number. If the start number is greater than the end number, the range will be empty. When you create a range like ```10..1```, it doesn't create a sequence of numbers from **10** to **1**. Instead, it checks if 10 is greater than 1, which it is, so it doesn't generate any numbers. So, you getting an empty list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `..` syntax is an alias for the [`rangeTo`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/range-to.html) function which gives an ascending range from the first to the last value inclusive.

So if the number following the `..` is less than number preceding, you get an empty range. This explains why you obtain an empty list when calling `map` on it.

If you want a descending range, you need to use the `downTo` function ([documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/ranges.html)):

```
println((10 downTo 1).map { it * 2 })
// prints [20, 18, 16, 14, 12, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2]
```

See [playground](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiMS45LjIyIiwicGxhdGZvcm0iOiJqYXZhIiwiYXJncyI6IiIsIm5vbmVNYXJrZXJzIjp0cnVlLCJ0aGVtZSI6ImlkZWEiLCJjb2RlIjoiZnVuIG1haW4oKXtcbiAgICBwcmludGxuKCgxMCBkb3duVG8gMSkubWFwIHsgaXQgKiAyIH0pXG59In0=).